# Python class instance evaluates to false?

Tags: python, dictionary, boolean

In the following example:

```
class Example(dict):
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  def get_name(self):
    return self.name

ex = Example('ex')
if ex:
  print(ex.get_name())
```

The `if ex` statement is evaluating to `False` and I am not getting any output. What is causing this instance to evaluate to `False`?

Comment: You've inherited from `dict` and an empty dict evaluates to `False`. What test are you trying to make? e.g. `if ex is not None:` would evaluate to `True`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You **inherit from `dict`**. The **[*truthiness*](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html) of a dictionary** (like almost every collection) **depends on whether it contains elements**. This holds for lists, sets, dictionaries and strings (a string is sometimes seen as an ordered collection of characters). Furthermore a lot of libraries have collections that follow the same rules (like counters, etc.).

You construct a dictionary here that does **not contain any elements**. So the truthiness is `False`.

You can however **override the truthiness** again, with:

```
class Example(dict):
      def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

      def __bool__(self):
          return True

      def get_name(self):
        return self.name
```

Note that whether you find the truthiness of such `Example(..)` with an underlying empty dictionary is a decision you have to make *yourself* (and of course it is better to follow "Python's guidelines). So the above code fragment is not *per se* correct for your application. It depends on what you want to do with it.

Furthermore it can be useful to pass additional unnamed arguments (`*args`) and named arguments (`**kwargs`) to the dictionary constructor to add elements to the underlying dictionary immediately as well as modifying the `__repr__` and/or `__str__` functions.

```
class Example(dict):
    def __init__(self, name,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.name = name

    def __bool__(self):
        return True

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
```